# How do i recover deleted page?

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, recycle-bin

I had a page which was not checked in was deleted by someone and also couldn't find it in recycle bin, how to recover such deleted pages?

Comment: You can also access recycle bin directly by accessing this page /_layouts/15/Recyclebin.aspx.This is for SP2013.

Answer (score 3):

You have an option of Secondary recycle Bin in SharePoint.
Go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Recycle bin.
if it is not appearing the deleted page. click on "second-stage recycle bin" link appearing as shown in below picture.

If you are not able to see still in that secondary recycle Bin. Your file permanently deleted.

[image]